# Liquid layout in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, liquid-layout

Is Liquid layout feasible in WPF? any concerns/questions we need to address when we make Liquid layout?

Does Liquid layout adjust the text font size and also adjust image width when it is small and big?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, most containers (called panels in WPF) support liquid layout, with the notable exception of Canvas that uses absolute coordinates. I don't think you should have any concerns.