# WPF responsive design (Liquid layout)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, responsive-design

I want to make my WPF application fully responsive application, I read a lot of posts about this topic, but unfortunately all of these postes does not helped my to accomplish what I want.

What I want to do is to make my application responsive like a website .. that mean if I have to `Buttons` arranged vertically and I minimize the width of the page, then the two `Buttons` should arranged horizontally. Like this:

> Normal Window

[image]

> After Resize

[image]

Is that possible in WPF? Is what I want to do called "Liquid layout" that mentioned in [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5934334/1890313) question?

Comment: Please post your xaml

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, one way to achieve that is by using a `WrapPanel`, and a hacky converter to ensure that the middle element takes all the remaining space:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:WpConverter x:Key="WpConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="BlueViolet" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <WrapPanel x:Name="wp" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel Width="100">
            <Rectangle Fill="CornflowerBlue" Height="20" Margin="3"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="CornflowerBlue" Height="20" Margin="3"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="CornflowerBlue" Height="20" Margin="3"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="CornflowerBlue" Height="20" Margin="3"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=wp,Converter={StaticResource WpConverter}}"></Grid>
        <Rectangle Margin="3" Fill="CornflowerBlue" Width="94" Height="200" ></Rectangle>
    </WrapPanel>
    <Rectangle Margin="3" Grid.Row="2" Fill="Cyan" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

</Grid>
```

The role of the converter is to make sure that the midle grid streatch to take all the remainning space (wrapanel width - left sidebar width - right sidebar width):

```
   public class WpConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Int32.Parse(value.ToString()) - 200;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Ps: you can also use a multivalue converter and pass the left and right sidebars' `ActualWidths` instead of hard coding their values in the converter.

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Make sure that you are binding to ActualWidth not Width

Comment: I copy and paste your code, but how to set  ActualWidth value ?

Comment: ActualWidth will be set automatically at runtime, you use it when you want to get the current width of a control lets say after resizing or something. Regarding the code above, it does work (the screen shot proves that ;)) )recheck your code, otherwise edit your question and pass it through and i will take a look;

Comment: Please check the test app https://www.mediafire.com/file/56w21mrr2glae07/WpfApp1.zip

Comment: Yes, it does work without a problem !! 
http://prntscr.com/kcgdqc
What Os your are into ?

Comment: Try changing the parse method in the converter, use tryParse, or an explicit cast
`return ((int)value) - 200;`

Comment: Unbelievable .. I got the error :
https://www.mediafire.com/file/54hys1a59qc2ljw/capture.PNG
https://www.mediafire.com/file/54hys1a59qc2ljw/capture2.PNG

Comment: OS Windows 10, VS 2017

Comment: Try what i've suggested and let me know

Comment: Unfortunately .. same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176974/discussion-between-elhamer-and-abdulsalam-elsharif).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think you should change the Grid inside WrapPanel to WrapPanel. Thanks again.